# Why does CDialog::DoModal return an INT_PTR and not an int as in very old SDKs

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

In the old times when 64 programming was something exotic, the `CDialag::DoModal()` function returned simply an `int`.

Now with recent SDKs `DoModal` returns an `INT_PTR` which is typedefed to an `int` if you compile for 32 bits, and it is typedefed to an `__int64` if you compile for 64 bits.

I'm currently adapting an old 32 bit application to 64 bits and of course I get a warning each time I have something like `int answer = someDialog.DoModal();`. The only clean solution is probably to replace all those `int`s by `INT_PTR`s (If anyone has a better idea, let me know).

Now does anybody know why the MFC folks at Microsoft didn't simply leave `int` as return type for `DoModal`? IMO there is no benefit using 64 bits rather than 32 bits for return values such as `IDOK`, `IDCANCEL` etc. There is probably a good reason but I cannot find one.

Comment: Well, MFC is a wrapper for the underlying native API which uses `INT_PTR` for dialog results, so it would be a *bug* if the return type of `DoModal()` would be `int`. Simply replace your types accordingly or use `static_cast<int>(someDialog.DoModal())` if you can be sure there is no overflow.

Comment: @zett42 OK, that sounds convincing, so the question should rather by "why did they switch from `int` to `INT_PTR` as return type in native  functions such as `DialogBoxParam` which return `INT_PTR` now and `int` in old SDKs.

Comment: I guess some people passed a pointer to `EndDialog`. The cast to `int` would be valid only for 32-bit. To be able to build such programs with only minor modifications for 64-bit, they had to extend the `EndDialog` parameter to `INT_PTR`.

Comment: @zett42's your last comment sounds most convincing to me. That makes sense.